# How can I return a struct's mutable member from and iterator's next method without allocations?

Tags: rust

I have the [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fd50a2f85545a44f9fac2596acd8d871):

```
struct MyIterator<'a> {
    data: &'a mut Vec<usize>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a [usize];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.data.push(1); // Mutate the Vec.
        Some(&self.data)
    }
}
```

But get this compile error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:10:14
   |
10 |         Some(&self.data)
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/lib.rs:8:13
   |
8  |     fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |             ^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:10:14
   |
10 |         Some(&self.data)
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/lib.rs:5:6
   |
5  | impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/lib.rs:8:46
   |
8  |       fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
   |  ______________________________________________^
9  | |         self.data.push(1);
10 | |         Some(&self.data)
11 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: expected `<MyIterator<'a> as Iterator>`
              found `<MyIterator<'_> as Iterator>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0495`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I could do the following where I clone my `data` struct member:

```
struct MyIterator<'a> {
    data: &'a mut Vec<usize>,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for MyIterator<'a> {
    type Item = Vec<usize>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.data.push(1);
        let data = self.data.clone();
        Some(data)
    }
}
```

However don't want to allocate a new `Vec` with each call of next. Is there any way I can have the same logic without allocations?

Comment: `push` may invalidate extant references to `data`. This code (if it compiled) would be unsound.

Comment: If that is so, then this would be a borrow checker bug, because it actually compiles like so: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f03701995e5053d33a3bd2293d8669c7

Comment: @Lagerbaer your example doesn't include `.push()`, which seems to be the crux of OPs issue

Comment: Can you clarify you want the iterator to return sequences of `[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], ...`?

Comment: Absolutely correct. Whoops. And in that case your high-level explanation is correct too.

Comment: OP, also please note that your playground code dropped the "push" part, which is really what this all comes down to. Made me write a correct answer for the wrong question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do cannot be done in the way you have it. As @trentcl explains, as you iterate, you're returning references to data. That means, however, that the data is borrowed. If that is so, you cannot then go on and mutably mess with the data via `push`.

Comment: It is still failing with the error message "error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*self.data` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference".

Comment: This is what I mean: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f03701995e5053d33a3bd2293d8669c7

Comment: You also removed `self.data.push(1)`. I think that is the reason why it compiled without the error I saw.

Comment: Correct. Please see the edit.

Comment: NOTE: The reason my example doesn't have the push is because OP's playground link doesn't have the push either...

Comment: @Lagerbaer sorry for the out of date playground reference.  Is there any way I can have the same logic as the first example without allocations?

Comment: The lifetimes error message does not get to the crux of the issue.

Comment: I think you should explain in your question a bit more what your desired behaviour is.